# clicking CANCEL in UISearchController navigates to previous ViewController

Tags: objective-c, uisearchcontroller

I create the UISearchController in `ViewDidLoad`

```
//create the search controller
    self.searchController = [[UISearchController alloc]initWithSearchResultsController:nil];
    self.searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = NO;
    self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;
    self.searchController.delegate = self;
    self.definesPresentationContext = YES;
    [self.searchBarHolder addSubview: self.searchController.searchBar];
    self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self;
```

when the users clicks the `CANCEL` button the following delegate method is called.

```
- (void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    self.searchController.active = NO;
    self.myTableView.hidden = YES;
    self.transparentViewSearch.hidden = YES;
}
```

The line `self.searchController.active=NO` navigates the user back to the previous view controller.

Additionally the line `self.transparentViewSearch.hidden = YES` does nothing. The view is still visible.

What is going on?

Answer (score 0):

```
you are using same table for showing search result
 self.searchController = [[UISearchController alloc]initWithSearchResultsController:nil];
```

You need to do update table after cancel search result.

```
[self.tableview reloadData];
```

then you need to do something like below.

```
  - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if(bShowSearchResult)
    {
        // return search result count
    }
    else
    {
        // return normal list count
    }
}

// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(bShowSearchResult)
    {
        　// create cell using search result data
        　Data = [lstSearchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        　//create cell
        　// return cell
    }
    else
    {
         Data = [lstFiles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
         //create cell
         // return cell
    }
}
```

I think it will help to you